# Math mode equation: Keep getting errors like Missing $ inserted, Extra } or forgotten $

Tags: math-mode, equations

i keep getting a lot of errors when compiling this equation:

```
\begin{center}{
$\textit{C} \in \{2^0, 2^1,..., 2^9\}; \textit{\gamma} \in \{\frac{2^0}{100},\frac{2^1}{100},..., \frac{2^6}{100}\}$
}\end{center}
```

Mainly the 'Missing $ inserted' and 'Extra }, or forgotten $' appear.
I tried all possible combinations of placing $, e.g. for every single \frac, using $$ or placing more {}.
I'm quite new to LaTex so maybe I just don't see the obvious ;)
thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Please show us the packages you have included. Though unrelated, `\cdots` may be used instead of the three dots `.`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The correct input is `\[C\in\{2^0, 2^1,\dots, 2^9\}; \gamma\in \{\frac{2^0}{100},\frac{2^1}{100},\dots, \frac{2^6}{100}\}\]`

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) sorry to say this, but you really need to have a look at some introductionary note about LaTeX. This is not how you write math

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  `$`, all by itself, makes single letters, both greek and latin, italic, so no special treatment is needed.  also, `\textit` puts you into text mode, and `\gamma` requires math mode.  just get rid of `\textit` and you should be (mostly) okay.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick reply!
just removing the \textit commands did the job.
Have a nice weekend :)

Answer (score 3):

Beginner's mistakes.

If you want to have a displayed equation, use

```
\begin{equation*}
<the equation>
\end{equation*}
```

So in your case you would have to type

```
\begin{equation*}
C\in\{2^0, 2^1,\dots, 2^9\}; 
\gamma\in \left\{\frac{2^0}{100},\frac{2^1}{100},\dots, \frac{2^6}{100}\right\}
\end{equation*}
```

(line breaks are irrelevant so long as there is no blank line in the `equation*` environment).

Note that the environment already puts you in math mode and you *don't* need `\mathit` or `\textit` around letters, because math mode italicizes automatically.

Minimal full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to add some mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation*}
C\in\{2^0, 2^1,\dots, 2^9\}; 
\gamma\in \left\{\frac{2^0}{100},\frac{2^1}{100},\dots, \frac{2^6}{100}\right\}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Never leave a blank line before a math display.

[image]

Please, do yourself a favor and consult a beginner's guide such as [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)

Comment: As a suggestion, may be add a space after ``;\ ``, or `;\quad` or `;\qquad`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why is LaTeX not robust to blank lines in math displays?

Comment: @JPi Error confinement; it was Knuth's precise choice.